# How to initialise graphics in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, paint, init

I have some code like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    for (GameObject object : GameArea.objects){
        graphics.fillRect(object.position.x, object.position.y,object.width, object.height);
    }
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    graphics.fillRect(GameArea.square.position.x,GameArea.square.position.y,GameArea.square.width, GameArea.square.height);
    for(GameObject object2 : GameArea.objects){
       graphics.fillRect(object2.position.x, object2.position.y,object2.width, object.height);
    }
}
```

It is in a class called FieldPanel. I'm calling it from the MainGame class like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //The following line does not work:
                fieldPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g);
            }
});
```

However, the line that does not work is causing me problems. How do I create a new graphics object to pass into the other class's method? And, also, when I do create it, what attributes etc. should it have? I'm not entirely sure what the Graphics class does, an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

`paintComponent(Graphics g)` method called automatically. You can not call it anywhere. But if you want to draw new graphics you can use `repaint()` method in fieldPanel like that.

in `fieldPanel`

```
public void draw(){
   GameArea.add(new GameObject());
   repaint();
}
```

in `MainGame`

```
  Timer t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fieldPanel.draw();
                }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use double bufferization. Just put it in your class

```
BufferedImage bmp = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics gf = bmp.getGraphics();
```

And use this gf for drawing.
Use timer for repaint your JComponent

```
  Timer t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    yourJComponent.repaint();
                }
    });
```

And override paintComponent() method like your first listing of code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){
   graphics.drawImage(bmp,
   0, 0, yourJComponent.width, yourJComponent.height,
   0, 0, bmp.width, bmp.height,
   null);
}
```

Sorry if i mistaken in fields. I don't remember by heart.